# Suppose H and K are subgroups of a group G. If |H| = 12 and |K| = 35, what is $|H \cap K|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know I have to use Lagrange's Theorem.

$H \cap K$ is a subgroup of H, so its cardinality divides that of $H$.  The same for $K$.  So then the cardinality of $H \cap K$ is a common divisor of the cardinalities of $H$ and $K$, but those are coprime, so it must be one.

Is this correct?

Comment: What can the cardinality of $H\cap K$ be?

Comment: You mean $H\cap K$ or $H\cup K$? The latter is hardly a subgroup in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$